# Minimizing the size of bundled JRE?

Tags: java, jvm

I'm trying to minimize the size of the JRE I have bundled with my application and its setup. Right now, the JRE takes up around 220mb whereas the application itself only takes up 20mb. The application itself can run on machines that have Java installed, but it can run on all machines only when I bundle the JRE using launch4j. What I am trying to achieve is, minimize the size of the JRE that I have bundled with my application but I do not know which components are required. How can I determine which components or directories of the JRE are only necessary for my program? I am fairly new to this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What version of Java are you using? What you need to do is considerably different depending on the version.

Comment: Your terminology tells me that you're either using or are used to an older Java version (something before Java 9), because the "JRE" hasn't been a thing for a good long while now in recent Java releases. Luckily [`jlink`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jlink.html) was introduced which allows you to build a very customized JDK subset to deliver with your product which does exactly what you're looking for. This also implies that your software needs to be running on at least Java 9 (and ideall 11 or 17, as those are the supported versions right now).

Comment: @JoachimSauer Not quite true. Most of major OpenJDK distributions ([Azul Zulu](https://www.azul.com/downloads/?version=java-17-lts&package=jre), [BellSoft Liberica](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-17-lts), [Adoptium](https://adoptium.net/archive.html?variant=openjdk17&jvmVariant=hotspot), [SapMachine](https://sap.github.io/SapMachine/), etc.) still offer JRE packages of Java 17.